# Deserializing JSON object says Input string is not a valid integer

Tags: c#, .net

i have this Json

```json
{
   "queryresult":{
      "responseMessage":"success",
      "customer":{
         "accountNumber":"8292829222",
         "meterNumber":"",
         "phoneNumber":"",
         "lastName":"CHRISTIAN ",
         "address":"2 OSISIOMA NGWA, ABIA",
         "city":null,
         "district":"Damata",
         "userCategory":"NON-MD",
         "customerType":"unmetered",
         "paymentPlan":"Postpaid",
         "vat":463.8525,
         "tariffCode":"R2SC-NMD",
         "tariffRate":53.78,
         "arrearsBalance":129324.8435,
         "billedAmount":6184.7,
         "billedDate":"08-2022",
         "lastPayDate":null,
         "lastpayment":{
            
         }
      },
      "responseCode":200,
      "status":"true"
   },
   "status":true
}
```

When i deserialize with

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(readTask);
```

it throws and error saying

Input String '463.8525' is not a valid integer

which is the `vat` field

How do i solve this issue? below is my model

```
   public class customer
{
    public string accountNumber { get; set; }
    public string meterNumber { get; set; }
    public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public object city { get; set; }
    public string district { get; set; }
    public string userCategory { get; set; }
    public string customerType { get; set; }
    public string paymentPlan { get; set; }
    public double vat { get; set; }
    public string tariffCode { get; set; }
    public double tariffRate { get; set; }
    public double? arrearsBalance { get; set; }
    public double billedAmount { get; set; }
    public string? billedDate { get; set; }
    public string? lastPayDate { get; set; }
    public Lastpayments lastpayment { get; set; }
}

public class Lastpayments
{
    public string transactionRef { get; set; }
    public int units { get; set; }
    public string transactionDate { get; set; }
    public string transactionId { get; set; }
    public int transactionBookId { get; set; }
    public int? amountPaid { get; set; }
    public int mscPaid { get; set; }
    public string invoiceNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Queryresults
{
    public string responseMessage { get; set; }
    public customer customer { get; set; }
    public int responseCode { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public Queryresults queryresult { get; set; }
    public bool status { get; set; }
}
```

The error points to the vat field. I tried using [JsonIgnore] to Ignore the vat field as i dont really need it but it dint work

Comment: Try telling the Json.DeserializeObject that you are deserializing a _customer_ _JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<customer>(....)_

Comment: Are you sure it's the `vat` field?  I'm going to strongly guess it's the `billedAmount` field.

Comment: `billedAmount` is defined as an `int` but the JSON string contains a double. Are you *sure* the JSON text, code and errors match? Post actual, compilable code that reproduces the problem. Something people can take and run without making assumptions

Comment: @Jonesopolis it is the vat field as it mention is in the error message. if the vat is 0 without a dot then it works well

Comment: Your example JSON and class definitions do not reproduce the problem for me. Is this the actual code and JSON that you are getting the error with?

Comment: Your JSON is deserialized fine https://dotnetfiddle.net/60pqgU

Comment: @Haybee Newtonsoft.Json has another message template for errors. Pls post the full original message.